# Facing issue while calling @RemoteAction in Salesforce VF and apex code

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am developing code for `@RemoteAction`. In this example once the user selected a particular opportunity stage name then calling the `@RemoteAction` to get the list of opportunities.

In my case, I am not getting the Opportunity Name value:

[image]

**OpportunityRemoteActionController**

```
 global with sharing class OpportunityRemoteActionController {

      public Opportunity opp{get;set;}
      public String stageName{get;set;}


      public OpportunityRemoteActionController() {    
      }
       /**
       * Method that creates the select option dynamically.
       **/
       public List<SelectOption> getOptions() {
           List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
          Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Opportunity.StageName.getDescribe();
          List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
          options.add(new SelectOption('--Select--', '--Select--'));

         for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple){
             //system.debug('f.getLabel()=>'+f.getLabel() +' ==f.getValue()' +f.getValue());
            options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
         }   
         return options;
      }

      /**
       * Remote action involved with Javascript remoting and is made global
       **/
        @RemoteAction
          global static Opportunity[] getOpportunityDetails(String stageNameDet) {
              return [select id,Name,Amount,stageName from Opportunity WHERE stageName =: stageNameDet];
          }
 }
```

**VFPage**

```
<apex:page controller="OpportunityRemoteActionController" showHeader="true">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getStageJS(){
 var oppStage= document.getElementById("{!$Component.theFm.oppStage}").value;  
  alert("stageName==>"+oppStage); 
  OpportunityRemoteActionController.getOpportunityDetails( oppStage,

    function(result, event){
         var html = '<table border="thick solid">';
          html = html + '<caption><b>Opportunity Details</b></caption><tr></tr>';
          html = html + '<tr><th>Opportunity Name</th>';
          html = html + '<th>Amount</th> </tr>';
         if (event.status && event.result) {
            debugger;
        // alert("event.result[0].Name==>"+event.result[0].Name);           
          for (var prop in event.result) {
          // important check that this is objects own property not from prototype prop inherited    
          //alert(prop + " = " + event.result[prop].Name);
          html = html + '<tr><td><a href="'+event.result[prop].Name+'</td> <td>'+event.result[prop].Amount+'</td></tr> ';
      }

       html = html + '</table>';


             alert("html==>"+html);
            $("#opportunityDetails").html(html);


      } else {

             alert(event.message);

      }

}, {escape:true});




}

 </script>

   <div align="center" width="550px">
      <apex:form id="theFm">
        <apex:selectList value="{!stageName}" size="1" id="oppStage" onchange="getStageJS()">
             <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
      </apex:form>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <br/>
   <div id="opportunityDetails" align="center">

         <!-- Opportunity details is displayed here. -->

   </div>
 </apex:page>
```

As per sdfcfox, below error comes:
[image]

and console error:[image]

Comment: Based on your code here: `<a href="'+event.result[prop].Name+'`, it's probably being put in the page as a link, and without an inner text node, there is nothing there to see or click on.

Comment: Make sure you're testing names that include quotes and other special characters to make sure your code doesn't break. Rendering raw HTML like this is probably not ideal.

Comment: @sfdcfox - How we can render the output when working with @RemoteAction? Any better approach ?

Comment: @javaHelper in jQuery, use `jQuery('<a />', { href: ... })` and the like to construct individual DOM elements that will be properly escaped, and then use `append` to build your node tree. You can do this without jQuery simply by using document.createElement, document.createTextNode, and Node.appendChild. I realize it's slightly more code to write, but has better performance and doesn't risk HTML injection.

Comment: I am not expert on JS/HTML side yet. Could you please provide something good to refer for this use case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing raw, plain HTML to inject is considered a [security risk](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). Instead, take the time to properly build your HTML using DOM elements:

```
<apex:page controller="OpportunityRemoteActionController" showHeader="true">
<script type="text/javascript">
function getStageJS(){
 var oppStage= document.getElementById("{!$Component.theFm.oppStage}").value;  
  OpportunityRemoteActionController.getOpportunityDetails( oppStage,

function(result, event){
    var root, table, a, caption, bold, text, tr, th, td;

    table = document.createElement("table");
    table.border = "thick solid";

    caption = document.createElement("caption");
    bold = document.createElement("b");
    text = document.createTextNode("Opportunity Details");
    bold.appendChild(text);
    caption.appendChild(bold);
    table.appendChild(caption);

    tr = document.createElement("tr");
    th = document.createElement("th");
    text = document.createTextNode("Opportunity Name");
    th.appendChild(text);
    tr.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    text = document.createTextNode("Amount");
    th.appendChild(text);
    tr.appendChild(th);

    table.appendChild(tr);

    if(event.status && event.result) {
        event.result.length = Object.keys(event.result).length;
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(event.result, function(row) {
            tr = document.createElement("tr");
            td = document.createElement("td");
            a = document.createElement("a");
            a.href = "/"+row.Id;
            text = document.createTextNode(row.Name);
            a.appendChild(text);
            td.appendChild(a);
            tr.appendChild(td);

            td = document.createElement("td");
            text = document.createTextNode(row.Amount || 0);
            td.appendChild(text);
            tr.appendChild(td);
            table.appendChild(tr);
        });
    }
    root = document.getElementById("opportunityDetails");
    while(root.firstChild) {
        root.removeChild(root.firstChild);
    }
    root.appendChild(table);
}, {escape:true});




}

 </script>

   <div align="center" width="550px">
      <apex:form id="theFm">
        <apex:selectList value="{!stageName}" size="1" id="oppStage" onchange="getStageJS()">
             <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
      </apex:form>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <br/>
   <div id="opportunityDetails" align="center">

         <!-- Opportunity details is displayed here. -->

   </div>
 </apex:page>
```

There's a jQuery equivalent if you want slightly shorter syntax, but you should at minimum consider constructing proper elements. This has better performance and fewer security risks.

Comment: @user4567570 That's a shame. Probably not a "real" array, so try `Array.prototype.forEach.call` instead (see answer).

Comment: I just tried your solution, some error comes, `Refused to display 'https://ap5.salesforce.com/apexpages/devmode/devConsoleViewStateMetadataReceiver.apexp' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`. I don't know what is this, otherwise could have tried to fixed t too. No data shown when selected from drop down..

Comment: @javaHelper let me test real quick

Comment: Nothing is displayed on the screen. Just saw error on console tab.

Comment: @javaHelper I have created a new version that I verified to work in Chrome. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @martin's comment, you haven't closed your `<a>` tag either.

So change this:

```
<a href="'+event.result[prop].Name+'
```

To this:

```
<a href="'+ event.result[prop].Name +'">' + '+ event.result[prop].Name +' + ' </a>
```

If you want the link go to the Opportunity, you should change the href value to the Opportunity Id as well:

```
<a href="/'+ event.result[prop].Id +'">' + '+ event.result[prop].Name +' + ' </a>
```

Comment: +1, but the href should also be using the record's Id, not its name.

Comment: realised that min ago and updated my answer

Comment: Added the fix - it's a relative url that you want and you need a slash for that - see my last line

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to update the Caspar's answer, still some minor changes are required. I have just shown one more column `Account Name`.

Changed below

```
<a href="'+ event.result[prop].Id +'">' + '+ event.result[prop].Name +' + ' </a>
```

To, Use below

```
<a href="'+ event.result[prop].Id +'">' +event.result[prop].Name+ ' </a>'
```

[image]

**When we click on any Opportunity Name, below error comes**

[image]

When I checked URL, it comes like `https://c.ap5.visual.force.com/apex/0067F000002blLrQAI`, 
I think it should simply come like

```
https://c.ap5.visual.force.com/0067F000002blLrQAI
```